# Google script remove spreadsheet row after 5 minutes

Tags: javascript, datetime, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google sheet being populated by google form responses. I want to remove responses that are older than 5 minutes.

This is what I have:

```
function duration() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var newData = new Array();
  var now = new Date();

  newData.push([("Timestamp") , ("First Name") , ("Last Name") , ("Homeroom")]);

  for(i in data){
    var row = data[i];
    if (now - row[0] < 300000) {
      newData.push(row);
    }
  }
  sheet.clearContents();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, newData.length, newData[0].length).setValues(newData);
}
```

It is only removing rows that are hours old.

I do not understand the time arithmetic:

```
now - row[0] < 300000
```

Isn't 300000ms = 5 minutes?

Comment: Quick tip... you can do almost any unit conversion very easily [with google](https://www.google.ca/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&q=300000ms%20to%20minutes&oq=300000ms%20to%20minutes&aqs=chrome..69i57j0.2079j0j7).

Comment: I don't see an array named `row`.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the operator be "greater than"?

```
 if (now - row[0] > 300000) {
```

Rather than:

```
 if (now - row[0] < 300000) {
```